# What is this application?

Tags: web-applications

QQ is probably the most popular IM software in China. When I log into QQ with my account, a news window pops up (see attached photo):

[image]

[image]

So my question is, is this news windows purely a webpage/application, which can be achieved via HTML/CSS/JS, or something else, like a software?

And just a another example:

Haofang Gaming Platform is also very popular among Chinese gamers. My English is plain, I don't know how to say this, but it basically connects people over the internet that intend to play a specific game with many others in a specific geographic location, which providing a LAN like very fast and stable gaming platform. So is this also a purely web application? because according to my humble knowledge, it can also be achieved roughly the same way as a webpage

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, choose Tools / Developer Tools from 'Settings' menu (CTRL + SHIFT + I) and click on magnifying glass icon (inspect element). Then click on for part of the page you want to inspect to see whether it is HTML or some applet.

Comment: I don't think it's even open in a web browser (proper). It sounds like MyMSN which opens up its own window with an embedded IE frame.

Comment: yes. it opens outside any web browsers, just pops up on desktop background when the main IM program has been initialized. I suspect its an applet but calls some webpage resources to feed the contents.